# Numba guvectorize exception due to Numpy ufunc signature

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I'm trying to use the `@guvectorize` decorator that will return the axis=0 means of an array from  vectors of starts and stops, so for example, if:

```
values = array([[82, 3],
                [76, 7],
                [23, 8],
                [46, 5],
                [38, 6]])
starts = array([ 0,  1,  1,  1,  4])
stops  = array([ 1,  4,  4,  4,  5])
```

My function would return:

```
array([[82.        ,  3.        ],
       [48.33333333,  6.66666667],
       [48.33333333,  6.66666667],
       [48.33333333,  6.66666667],
       [38.        ,  6.        ]])
```

Following the [simple example in the numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator), this is what I came up with (function operates over the vector of one column):

```
@guvectorize([(int64[:], int64[:], int64[:], float64[:])], '(n),(n),(n)->(n)', nopython=True)
def variable_window_avg(values, starts, stops, means):
    for i in range(values.shape[0]):
        means[i] = np.nanmean(values[starts[i]:stops[i]])
```

This works great when `values` is a vector, but does not scale up when values is an ndarray as desired:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-8a213e6ace9c> in <module>
----> 1 variable_window_avg(arr[:,:2], arr[:,1], arr[:,2])

ValueError: variable_window_avg: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n),(n),(n)->(n) (size 100 is different from 2)
```

The error suggests the shapes are not broadcasting together correctly via the Numpy generalized universal functions API, and indeed

```
res = variable_window_avg(values.T, starts, stops)

res = res.T
```

works. But modifying the input and output layouts signature would seem the better solution to avoid two transposes. I also don't understand why the example in the numba documentation but my code fails.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the purpose of the algorithm is to obtain the average of a vector's slice. For example, having vector [1,2,3,4,5] and slice 1:4, the result would be 3. Please correct me if I got the wrong idea.

The idea behind vectorization is not to implement the function knowing the dimensions you will be using. Instead, you only need to implement the "kernel" or the simplest case. For this algorithm, it would be:

```
@nb.guvectorize([(nb.int64[:], nb.int64, nb.int64, nb.float64[:])],
                '(n),(),()->()', nopython=True)
def variable_window_avg(values, start, stop, means):
    means[:] = np.nanmean(values[start:stop])
```

Note that the signature `'(n),(),()->()'` indicates that the input is a vector and two scalars, and the output is another scalar. The vectorization mechanism will extend the dimensions according to the input parameters in each case.

For example, the simplest case doesn't need any vectorization:

```
>>> variable_window_avg([3,7,8,5,6], 1, 4)
6.666666666666667
```

When using several index pairs, vectorization is applied:

```
>>> variable_window_avg([3,7,8,5,6], [0,1,4], [1,4,5])
array([3.        , 6.66666667, 6.        ])
```

Also when using a 2D array and a single index pair:

```
>>> variable_window_avg([[82,76,23,46,38], [3,7,8,5,6]], 1, 4)
array([48.33333333,  6.66666667])
```

But when using the array and multiple indices there is a broadcasting problem:

```
>>>> variable_window_avg([[82,76,23,46,38], [3,7,8,5,6]], [0,1,4], [1,4,5])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../numba/np/ufunc/gufunc.py", line 151, in __call__
    return self.ufunc(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (2,6)->(2,) (3,)->(3,) (3,)->(3,)  and requested shape ()
```

So you need to transpose the indices:

```
>>> variable_window_avg([[82,76,23,46,38], [3,7,8,5,6]], [[0],[1],[4]], [[1],[4],[5]])
array([[82.        ,  3.        ],
       [48.33333333,  6.66666667],
       [38.        ,  6.        ]])
```

Transposing the input array instead of the indices won't work because the function performs the slicing at the innermost level of the array.